# How to web scrape a .aspx Web page in Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, vbscript, www-mechanize

i'm trying to create an script that automates the logging in to a website that seems to have some embedded VBscript and Javascript and I am wondering how I can create an auto-login script with WWW::Scripter. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you really mean "scrape"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.53/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) you'll save yourself a lot of work/problems. That said I doubt any browser but IE executes client side VBS.

Comment: I kinda need to use IE, the website is weird and wont allow any other browser other than IE

Comment: Hmm, that suck's try Win32::IE::Mechanize : http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Win32-IE-Mechanize-0.009/lib/Win32/IE/Mechanize.pm

Comment: is there a problem with using WWW::Scripter?

Comment: @user801867 if as you say the site only works in IE, you'll need to drive IE, WWW::Scripter does not drive IE.